# JSONArray problem, cant get data, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-volley

**I have a problem with JsonArrayRequest,can't pull data from the "openweathermap" API, when I do the same thing with StringRequest, it pulls the data without any problem. But it doesn't work with JsonArrayRequest.**

```
btn_cityID.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                String apikey = "//";
                String url = "//";

                JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response){
                        
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
//             StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onResponse(String response) {
//
//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    }
//                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    }
//                });


                queue.add(request);


            }
        });
```

**API response:**

{
"coord": {
"lon": -0.1257,
"lat": 51.5085
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 500,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "light rain",
"icon": "10d"
}
],
"base": "stations",
"main": {
"temp": 285.39,
"feels_like": 285.1,
"temp_min": 284.32,
"temp_max": 286.08,
"pressure": 1007,
"humidity": 93
},
"visibility": 10000,
"wind": {
"speed": 7.2,
"deg": 210
},
"rain": {
"1h": 0.27
},
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"dt": 1671445217,
"sys": {
"type": 2,
"id": 2075535,
"country": "GB",
"sunrise": 1671436957,
"sunset": 1671465146
},
"timezone": 0,
"id": 2643743,
"name": "London",
"cod": 200
}

Comment: send api response..

Comment: API response is JSONObject and you are calling it with JsonArrayRequest. Use JsonObjectRequest instead

Comment: you can convert **JSONArray** or **JSONObject** from **string response** using **StringRequest**